# Программное узнавание координат точки в яндекс или гугл картах

Tags: java, html, google-maps

Из предыдущего вопроса узнал, что нажимать кнопку программно можно с помщью спец.библиотеки.
Вопрос: как мне извлечь координаты места из гугл или яндекс карт, если на вход я загоняю название и наживаю кнопку поиск.

Answer (score 1):

В Яндекс API есть инструмент - геокодер.

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/

**Геокодер**

API для перевода географических координат в адрес и **наоборот**.

Вот его документация:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

То есть,

1. формируем запрос к яндексу
2. Обрабатываем полученный список результатов

**UPD:**
Если в яндекс придется дергать по URL JSON или XML, то в Гугл с этим дела обстоят гораздо лучше.

Есть библиотека с открытым исходным кодом:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

И документация к ней:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/client-library

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, с помощью той же библиотеки Selenium ты можешь открыть браузер, перейти на maps.google.ru, в поле поиска вбить нужную тебе строку, которую ты будешь искать, далее нажать кнопку с лупой, и после этого уже забрать URL и распарсить его

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://maps.google.ru");
WebElement searchBoxForm = driver.findElement(By.id("searchbox_form"));
WebElement input = searchBoxForm.findElement(By.id("searchboxinput"));
element.sendKeys(myFindString);
searchBoxForm.findElement(By.className("searchbutton")).click();
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl(); // тут получаете URL и парсите его
```